# How to control global variable in unitTest

Tags: java, variables, junit

Is it possible to control the value of the global variable in the class that I test?
The global variable is used in a private method, so I use a public method (in the same class) to pass through it.

How can I say that `mListValService != null`?

```
public class Myclass {

  //my global variable
  private ListValServiceRemote listValService = null;

  public String getCodeValeurRef(Long idValeur) {
    return getListValService().getRlvCode(idValeur);

    // I want 100% coverage on this method so i have to change the value 
    // of mListValService.
    private ListValServiceRemote getListValService() {
      if (listValService == null) {
        listValService = ServiceGetter.getListValService();
      }
      return listValService;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you say it's global? Do you miss `static` from the code snipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) from spring-test might be a solution to access the field value. You can also use plain old reflection, add getter/setter to the field or make the field `protected` and put the test in the same package as the tested class.

Sample test:

```
public class MyclassTest {
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetListValServiceWhenFieldIsNull() {
        assertNotNull(this.myClass.getListValService());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetListValServiceWhenFieldIsNotNull() {
        final ListValServiceRemote  lvsr = new ListValServiceRemote();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.myClass, "listValService", lvsr);
        assertSame(lvsr, this.myClass.getListValService());
    }
}
```

Comment: ReflectionTestUtils.setField() worked for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the `getListValService()` method as package-private, then call it in a test. You can confirm the same value is returned each time:

```
@Test
public void sameListValTest() {
  Myclass foo = // construct this somewhow

  assertTrue(foo.getListValService() == foo.getListValService());
}
```

This will give you 100% coverage without fiddling with a private field.

Or you could just call `getCodeValeurRef()` twice in your test to achieve the same results. Anything that causes the `getListValService()` to execute twice will give you 100% coverage. Exposing it as package-private allows you to verify that you are re-using the same field, not creating one each time (if that's important).

Comment: It's a bad sign if you need to expose some members just for unit testing.

Comment: @kan On the whole I agree. There are exceptions and it's difficult to determine whether this is one, based on what we know so far.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, seems you are not using IoC technique, and hence you have problems while unit testing the code.

Secondly, a private is the private, don't test it. Your code should be tested and covered only by using public methods. If some code is not reachable via public interface, then it is not reachable at all. Why do you want to test it then?

This particular code could be easily 100% covered if you just invoke `getCodeValeurRef()` twice. And also if you would have `listValService == null`, it will cause NullPointerException failing the test anyway, so an assert is not required.